# <video> won't play Apple Trailer URLs

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I'm trying to include a HTML5 video player on a site.

I've got the following code:

```
<video id="player" controls="controls" width="100%">
    <source src="http://trailers.apple.com/movies/paramount/captainamerica/captainamerica-tlr1_h.480.mov">
</video>
```

This works in Safari, but not in Chrome and Firefox, is the .mov encoded in a weird way that doesn't allow them to be used like this? trailers.apple.com which uses the same URLs work fine in their player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability that on apple's site they have multiple links to different encoded movie files. They do this because there is no current movie format that works across all major browsers.

Also just because the URL is the same doesn't mean that the same video is being served up on apples website... They could be doing some URL mapping magic to get a correct video format.

look at this link for a good current table of support per codec

http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html#what-works

Comment: Yeah OK, "Movie trailers on Apple’s website still use the older QuickTime container, but movies that you rent from iTunes are delivered in an MPEG 4 container." might be the problem then :(

Comment: @runmad Well im glad that I could steer you to a good reference..BTW I think everyone who is interested in learning the basics of HTML5 should read that Book\Online reference IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Apple only serves up their videos in the MOV format.  This means that only Safari can watch the videos since it is the only browser that uses Quicktime in its HTML5 video implementation.  If you try opening the file directly in Chrome you should either see it download or the Quicktime plugin kick off.

I personally don't have Quicktime so when I go to the Apple trailers site, I get a link to download Quicktime and can't proceed any further without doing so.

Answer (score 0):

`captainamerica-tlr1_h.480.mov` is just a .mov file that redirects to `captainamerica-tlr1_h480.mov` But it still won't work in browsers that doesn't use Quicktime for `<video>`. You have to set User-Agent to "Quicktime" for `trailers.apple.com`.

Answer (score -2):

other browsers doesn't understand .mov, quicktime does. you need to serve up separate files for safari. you can generate needed files with nero or in-browse via media.io.

Comment: I think you misread.  It is working in Safari since Safari leverages Quicktime as the backend for its `<video>` implementation.  Its other browsers that don't use Quicktime that are having the issue.

Comment: Safari plays the files fine, I had problems with Chrome/FireFox. As you might have guessed from reading my question, I am wanting to stream the video from Apple's trailer site, not re-encode it.

Comment: we all misread it. ok, thats why it doesn't work in other browsers. they don't understand .mov